# Is it possible to nest a tibble passed to rlang::dots_list?

Tags: r, rlang

I have a 2x2 tibble `x` that I want to send to a function `f`. I use `rlang::dots_list()` within `f` to extract all named parameters sent to `f` as ellipsis (`...`). The result from `rlang::dots_list()` is coerced into a `tibble` data structure.

```
# MRE
x <- tibble::tibble(
    a = base::sample(base::letters, size = 2),
    b = base::sample(base::letters, size = 2)
  )

f <- function(...){
  rlang::dots_list(...) %>%
    tibble::as_tibble()
}

f(parameter = '1', x_name = x)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  parameter x_name$a $b   
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>
1 1         c        r    
2 1         v        g
```

```
# Expected behaviour
f(parameter = '1', x_name = x)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  parameter x_name$data     
  <chr>     <list>          
1 1         <tibble [2 x 2]>
```

I reach the expected block above by resetting `x` to `x <- tidyr::nest(x, data = tidyr::everything())`.

```
# Trials
f <- function(...){
  rlang::dots_splice(...) %>%
    tibble::as_tibble()
}

f <- function(...){
  as_tibble(
    !!!rlang::dots_list(...)
  )
}

f <- function(...){
  as_tibble(...)
}

f <- function(...){
  as_tibble(
    !!rlang::dots_list(...)
  )
}
```

Comment: What if you just use `tibble` in this way: `tibble(parameter = '1', x_name = list(x))` ? Which returns exactly what you would expect. Basically, `f` would be the function `tibble`. You just need to set `x` into its own list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Edo's comment you could implement his solution using `purrr::map_if` and check if the object is a data.frame then if it is apply list to it:

```r
f <- function(...){
  rlang::dots_list(...) %>% purrr::map_if(is.data.frame, list) %>% tibble::as_tibble 
}
f(parameter = '1', x_name = x)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  parameter x_name          
  <chr>     <list>          
1 1         <tibble [2 × 2]>
```